# How should I write the factors in polynomial division if I know the polynomials roots?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials

If a polynomial $P(x)$ has a root at $x=0.5$ and I do polynomial division on $P(x)$, would I divide it by $(x-0.5)$ or $(2x-1)$? Are both equally valid? Furthermore, would it be okay to write the polynomial in factored form as $P(x) = (x-0.5) \cdot Q(x)$, or should I have integer coefficients?

Comment: Both are valid. Integer coefficient are not necessary to write the polynomial. If you make polynomial division you use the linear factor $(x-0.5)$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since $2x+1 = 2(x+\frac{1}{2})$ you can divide your polynomial $P(x)$ by both.

$$P(x) = Q(x)\cdot\left(x+\frac{1}{2}\right)$$

$$P(x) = Q(x)\cdot(2x+1)\cdot \frac{1}{2} = Q'(x)\cdot(2x+1)$$

Obviusly dividing won't give you the same $Q(x)$, but both solutions would be related by $Q(x)=2Q'(x)$

Answer (score 0):

Dividing by either is fine, the only significant difference is the aesthetics. For example if $P(x) = 2x^2 + x - 1$ then P(x) = (x - 0.5)(2x + 2) and also P(x) = (2x - 1)(x + 1)$

Answer (score 0):

The set of polynomials with coefficients in a ring $\mathbb{R}$ is a ring. Every ring is a module over itself. If $\mathbb{R}=\mathbb{K}$ is a field, the ring of polynomials is a $K$-algebra, hence in particular

$$\alpha\left[f(x)g(x)\right]=[\alpha f(x)]g(x)=f(x)[\alpha g(x)]$$
for all $\alpha\in \mathbb{K}$. Hence you may write equivalently
$$\frac{1}{2}\left[f(x)g(x)\right]$$
or $$f(x)\left[\frac{1}{2}g(x)\right]$$
or $$\left[\frac{1}{2}f(x)\right]g(x)$$

which in your case is respectively
$$\frac{1}{2}(2x+1)g(x)$$
or
$$(2x+1)\frac{1}{2}g(x)$$
or
$$(x+\frac{1}{2})g(x)$$

Answer (score 0):

If $\alpha, \beta $ are roots then the polynomial can be expressed as

$$ a (x-\alpha)(x-\beta) $$

where $a$ is a constant. So division by either one of the factors is alright.

Either way polynomial is the same, with different factors the constants are different.

$$ 2x^2+x -1= 1(x-\frac12)(2x+2)= 2(x-\frac12)(x+1)$$